# Get_parent_name of custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I Use "**get_queried_object**" and get an array:

```
stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 10 [name] => Kem nền [slug] => kem-nen [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 10 [taxonomy] => muc-san-pham [description] => [parent] => 16 [count] => 6 [filter] => raw )
```

And I know [Parent]= 16. I want to get [Name] of  [Parent] = 16 . But i don't know how to get name? Please help me!

Comment: Please format your code for better readability. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query you will get the parent id.
So you can use this to get parent name.

```
get_the_title(16);
```